# How does Entity get to look at the camera?

Tags: python, ursina

The following is the code about entity, which is a flat message in Usina

```py
from ursina import *


class message(Entity):
    def __init__(self, entity_position:Entity, y_up = 4, msg="☕"):
        super().__init__(
            model="quad",
            texture="src/message.png",
            position=Vec3(entity_position.position) + Vec3(0, y_up, 0)
        )

        self.entity_position = entity_position
        self.y_up = y_up
```

I want this entity to look at the camera

But when I used this code,

```py
def update(self):
        self.look_at(camera)
```

I couldn't see the entity.

by the way,
When I use this code,

```py
def update(self):
        self.look_at(camera.ui)
```

I can see the entity, but entity is'not looking at the camera

Then,
How can i solve it?

Comment: If I am behind you and I look at the real camera that you are holding to take a picture of something else, will you be able to see me in the shot? Maybe instead of trying to make the message "look at" the camera, you should be trying to make the *camera* look at the *message*?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't see your Entity is because you're looking at the quad from behind, when only one of the sides are visible. This is because by default, look_at makes the forward axis point at the position, not the back vector. This is an extra argument you can pass to it though, `'back'`, `'left'`, `'up'`, etc.

However, the easiest solution would be to use the billboard property, which makes it face the camera every frame without having to call look_at in update:

```py
message = Entity(model="quad", texture="message.png", billboard=True)
```